# How to ident raw json while showing in UI?

Tags: html, angular

I need to show json in my angular application.

I am able to render the json but its coming in single line without line breaks and proper indentation. How can I prettify the json?

[image]

```js
 json = JSON.stringify({'widget': {
    'debug': 'on',
    'window': {
        'title': 'Sample Konfabulator Widget',
        'name': 'main_window',
        'width': 500,
        'height': 500
    },
    'image': { 
        'src': 'Images/Sun.png',
        'name': 'sun1',
        'hOffset': 250,
        'vOffset': 250,
        'alignment': 'center'
    },
    'text': {
        'data': 'Click Here',
        'size': 36,
        'style': 'bold',
        'name': 'text1',
        'hOffset': 250,
        'vOffset': 100,
        'alignment': 'center',
        'onMouseUp': 'sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;'
    }
}});
```

```html
 <code id="divv"> {{ json }} </code>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `pre` tag as shown below, along with angular JSON pipe.

```
<pre>{{data | json}}</pre>
```

<kbd>**[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ok5cqo?file=src/app/app.component.html)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same probleme a while ago but here you can use this function to beautify json:

```
function beautifyJsonString(jsonString) {
    try {
        return JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonString), null, 4);
    } catch (e) {}
    return jsonString;
}
```